# SQL Create Data for Database

Tags: sql

I would like to create a script to insert data into an SQL database.

My project is to take an access database, that isn't well structured and put it into SQL.  The access data can be imported, but there is a table that i have created to that the access DB doesn't have, which is what i want the script for.  Its a physical Paper box archive database.  I need to create the "Locations" data.

To be more specific the data is:

ID (auto num)
Rack - These are the shelving units
Row - This is the same as shelf
Column - This is the amount of boxes horizontally on a shelf
Position - This is the depth (there can be two boxes in the same column on each shelf)

Comment: Are you just wanting random data for N number of rows to be generated? If not, can you be a little more clear in what you are trying to achieve? (What does your table look like, how would this data look like that is being generated, what logic would we employ if we were to generate this data by hand, etc)

Comment: Please tag *only* the correct RDBMS. MySQL and SQL Server are not the same thing. As for getting data into a database, you use `INSERT`. Can't really add much more than that, as your question is incredibly vague.

Comment: I would urge you to read your question and ask yourself if you would be able to provide an answer based solely on the information in this post. We don't even know what you are asking help with. The "skeleton" of a script to insert data maybe. That would be "INSERT INTO...."

Comment: Is this question just "How do I migrate data from Access to a sql database"?  I'm totally fascinated by the vagueness of this question.

Answer (score 0):

**INSERT INTO**

In terms of script, there are a few methods of inserting data into MySQL. Firstly if you have an existing table, you can insert values into specific columns like so:

```
INSERT INTO TableName (Column1, Column2 etc..)
VALUES ("Column1 value", 420 etc...)
```

This can be added to a while loop in order to fill multiple rows at a fast pace.

**IMPORT FILE**

Another method you can use to create a table with existing data and columns is to import an excel sheet for example. This can be done by right clicking on the database you wish to add the new table to, heading to tasks then import data.

Database (Right Click) > Tasks > Import Data...

You will then need to select data source, presumably excel, then specify the file path. Next select destination; probably SQL Server Native Client for you. The rest from there should be pretty easy to follow.

**BULK IMPORT**

I've not had a lot of practice with bulk importing to SQL, however from what I am aware you can use this method to import data from an external file into a SQL table programmatically.

An example I have is as follows:

```
--Define the data you are importing in a temp table
CREATE TABLE #ClickData
         ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
        ,Dated VARCHAR(255)     COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
        ,PageViews VARCHAR(255) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AS
        )   

insert into #ClickData
--Select the data from the file
select Dated, PageViews
from openrowset(--Openrowset is the method of doing this
bulk 'FilePath\ImportToSqlTest.csv',--The file you wish to import data from
formatfile = 'FilePath\Main.XML',--The XML formatting for the data you are gathering (I believe this part is for reading the file)
firstrow = 2--Specifiy the starting row(Mine is 2 to ignore headers)

) as data
```

Apologies if this answer isn't overly helpful, I had to write this in a rush. I'm not entirely sure what you're looking for, as others stated your question is very vague. Hopefully this might help somewhat.